# Java, discord: Как получить роль после нажатия кнопки? Мне нужно получить роль после нажатия на кнопку CS2Button

Tags: java, бот, discord, discord-jda

```
public class Reaction implements ICommand {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "reaction";
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "Reaction";
    }

    @Override
    public List<OptionData> getOptions() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(SlashCommandInteractionEvent event) {
        EmbedBuilder embedBuilder = new EmbedBuilder();
        embedBuilder.setTitle("Keep Role");
        embedBuilder.setDescription("Roles");

        Button C2Button = Button.danger("CS2", "CS2");
        Button DotaButton = Button.danger("Dota", "Dota");


        Message message = new MessageBuilder()
                .setEmbeds(embedBuilder.build())
                .setActionRows(ActionRow.of(C2Button, DotaButton))
                .build();

        if (event.equals("C2button")) {

        }

        Member member = event.getMember();
        Guild guild = event.getGuild();
        Role role = guild.getRoleById(1202968341183209483L);
        guild.addRoleToMember(member, role).queue();
        event.reply("Role Added").queue();

        event.reply(message).queue();
    }
}
```